# What happens when TFS Build is stopped manually?

Tags: tfs, build-process, tfsbuild, build-automation

What happens when TFS Build is stopped manually? Does the control go inside the build template when a build is stopped? or is it just stopping the build agent process? From what I have read so far, I think that the control doesnt go inside the build template.

Is it possible to run some custom code when the TFS Build is stopped manually from build explorer? Here is the issue, we have our build template calling other batch files to do certain things. When a build is stopped manually and restarted, we get the "cant access the files, as it is used by another process error". I believe this is caused since the batch file is still holding onto it. So I am trying to kill the associated processes when the build is stopped.